# How to handle exceptions from any task in an event loop?

Tags: python-asyncio

I would like to stop the program, i.e. the event loop, if any task anywhere raises an unhandled exception. The normal behaviour is that you get a `Task exception was never retrieved` error message and the individual task stops, but the loop continues to run all other tasks.

For example:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("hi")

async def bug():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    raise TypeError

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(foo())
loop.create_task(bug())
loop.run_forever()
```

---

Output:

```
"hi"
"hi"
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<bug() done, defined at <...>:9> exception=TypeError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-bd8651340a75>", line 11, in bug
    raise TypeError
TypeError
"hi"
"hi"
"hi"
...
```

My project contains many dozens of coroutines spread over many files which add each other to the loop with `loop.create_task(foo())` so because they don't `await` each other, you cannot simply handle one or two entry point coroutines in the main file and have errors bubble up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found what I'm looking for with `loop.set_exception_handler(handler)`

Comment: That's it, but be careful, though, the exception handler is [sometimes called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021212/1600898) for exceptions that are actually caught. If you control the tasks being spawned, the alternative is to catch any exceptions thrown by the task (except perhaps `CancelledErrror`) and propagate them to a global future, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53691009/1600898).

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342. Both alternative methods are available to me, namely the `set_exception_handler` or the await global future solution. I like the former option as I'm single-threaded and it seems conceptually cleaner but should I be concerned by unreliability and other library bugs similar to those in the link?

Comment: Personally I'd prefer to catch the exceptions raised by the tasks I create and propagate them myself. Judging by the SSL issue, it seems that there is code out there that uses `set_exception_handler` as a substitute for logging. This is really a perfect use case for the new `TaskGroup` concept.